# Woocommerce Styling Prices after decimal Place

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a way to insert custom style to the digits after the decimal for woocommerce? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with positional pseudo class selectors.

I don't have an exact answer for you right now so I apologize in advance for keeping this short. However, you'll want to look at adding CSS to **.amount** class. For more information, review this blog post here http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/.

Comment: thanks for the look and input Michael :). ive read that article and the closest will be lettering.js but i was wondering if there can be a function to perform this because i have figures like $100.23, $10.23, $1.23.